# How to create a list that shows all unique workers that had service on a week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a query that shows the list of the workers that have at least a shift during the week, but in the query that I created the names of the workers appear multiple times according to the number of shifts they have completed during the period.

```
WITH time_frame AS
  (SELECT date_trunc('week',NOW())-interval '1 week')
  
select 
    null as "Employer Ref",   
    ff.id as "Personnel Ref", 
    null as "Employment Sequence No",
    ff.first_name as Forename, 
    ff.last_name as Surname,  
    null as "Second forename",
    null as "Third forename ",
    
    
    case ff.gender
    when 'F' then 'Miss' 
    when 'M' then 'Mr' 
    else null 
    end as Title,
    
    null as "Known as",            
     
    ff.address1 as "Address line 1",
    ff.address2 as "Address line 2",
    ff.city as "Address line 3",
    null as "Address line 4",
    null as "Address line 5",
    
    
    lp.postcode as Postcode,
    'UK' as Country,
    null as "Telephone number",    
    
    ff.gender as gender,
    ff.birth_date as "Date of birth",
    ff.mobile as "Mobile Telephone",
    au.email as "Email Address",
    ff.sort_code as "Bank1 sort code",
    ff.account_number as "Bank1 account number",
    concat(ff.first_name,' ',ff.last_name) as "Bank1 account name" 
    
    
    
    
    

from booking_booking bb 

join freelancer_freelancer ff on  bb.freelancer_id = ff.id
join job_jobrequest jj on bb.jobrequest_id = jj.id
join auth_user au on au.id = ff.user_id
join location_postcode lp on lp.id = jj.postcode_id



WHERE bb.status != 'FC'
     AND bb.status != 'BC'
     AND bb.status != 'BU'
     AND jj.agency_id IN('1')
     AND date_trunc('week',jj.date) =
       (SELECT *
        FROM time_frame)
```

Comment: It would be easier too answer your question if you would also post the structure of the involved tables and some sample data. Furthermore, could you try to simplify the query? Maybe the problem already arises when joining only 2 or 3 tables. Then, posting the simplified query (and only the tables involved in it) also simplifies the life of those trying to understand your problem.

Comment: (1) I am guessing that you could significantly simplify your query to illustrate your issue.  (2) Without sample data and desired results, it is really hard to understand your issue.